# Prevent Users from Entering Multiple Decimals In A String

Tags: objective-c

I am doing a button calculator app (still) in which users press a button, I store a value into a string to display in a text box, and then convert into floats when the user enters the = button.

Works great for the most part, except I cannot figure out how to prevent users from entering more than one decimal in a single string. I thought about passing it to a BOOL method, but none of my class materials cover methods at all.

I looked at this Stack overflow question, but trying to amend the code for my own just resulted in a whole bunch of errors. Does anyone have any advice?

```
    -(IBAction) decimal
    {
     NSString *decVal =@".";
     NSRange range = [decVal rangeOfString:@"."];

     if (range.location==NSNotFound)
      {
        display.text = [display.text stringByAppendingString:decVal];
      }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"You can't enter more than one decimal");
    }
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-(IBAction) decimal
{
    static NSString *decVal =@".";
    NSRange range = [display.text rangeOfString:decVal];

    if (NSNotFound == range.location)
    {
        display.text = [display.text stringByAppendingString:decVal];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"You can't enter more than one decimal");
    }
}
```

You have missed in one string. `[decVal rangeOfString:@"."]` will always return range {0,1}.

Comment: *Facepalm* I knew it was something sweet and simple like that. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

One way to handle this would be to set the delegate of the text field/view and then implement `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` in the delegate.

For example, you could do something like this:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    BOOL hasPeriod = ([textField.text rangeOfString:@"."].location != NSNotFound);
    BOOL removingPeriod = ([[textField.text substringWithRange:range] 
                                 rangeOfString:@"."].location != NSNotFound);
    BOOL addingPeriod = ([string rangeOfString:@"."].location != NSNotFound);
    return (hasPeriod && addingPeriod && !removingPeriod) ? NO : YES;
}
```

This won't throw an error. It just won't allow a second period. You could easily add in the error message, though.